# For Loop is not redefining what's supposed to be defined

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this `for` loop in which I'm trying to replace an index in `underlineArr` with a character and whenever I try to redefine it so It saves the current variable so I'm able to access it and change it later, nothing is being saved, It keeps using the default array while I'm trying to get the newly edited array.

**For Loop**:

```js
       const content = collected.content.toLowerCase();
           for (let i = 0; i < underlineArr.length; i++) {
               msg = underlineArr[i] = word[i] == content && underlineArr[i] == "_" ? content : "_";
           }
           msg = underlineArr.join(" ");
           console.log(msg);
```

This is the `underlineArr` constant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtzj2.png

This is the `word` constant: `"French Toast"`, Please note the constant is random from an array I created.

Lastly, `collected.content` is just a string returned.

The output: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mi8b.png)

Expected output:

```js
_ r _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ r e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ r e n _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ r e n c _ _ _ _ _ _ _
.....
```

Comment: Rather than putting information that is necessary to reproduce the results an image, please add them to your question.

Comment: After your for loop, you reassign `msg` and that erases the assignment inside the loop.

Comment: Also, the line inside the loop is one of the single most unreadable lines of code i have ever read, it uses chained assignment boolean conditions without parens and a ternary.... Remember there are no points for stuffing as much logic as you can onto a single line.

Comment: Expected ouput is quite clear... But what about the inputs (`content `, `word`, `underlineArr`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the index of `content` character instead of assigning the entire string.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < underlineArr.length; i++) {
   underlineArr[i] = word[i] == content && underlineArr[i] == "_" ? content[i] : "_";
}
```

Comment: I don't think that works, I've tried it but it still does the same thing but the letter isn't shown.. https://gyazo.com/a7dd7802d25a2979a62a374cc6f68fe7

Answer (score 0):

What about this... Am I cold or hot on that unclear question?

```js
let word = "French Toast".split("")
let underlineArr = Array(word.length).fill("_")
let result = []
word.forEach((char,i) => {
  let row = [...underlineArr]
  row[i] = word[i]
  result.push(row)
})

multiline = result.map(subarr => subarr.join(" ")).join("\n")

console.log(multiline)
```

Comment: Something such as that, but I was wondering if It's possible to save the `row[i] = word[i]`, so later I'm able to display the full word as well as log it.

Comment: Okay... Like to have it ALL in one *"multiline"* string that would be easy to use after... I edited

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but that doesn't seem what the expected output should be, I'm trying to make a hangman game and I have something like that already, it just doesn't allow me to save the constant which has the `word?`

Comment: A hangman game?!? lolll. I was lightyears from getting that is what you wish to achieve. I taught that was about producing some kind of a semi-ugly/semi-cool thing to throw out on Discord for fun. -- That makes your question more than unclear. I will stop my contribution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what I did, but I'm pretty sure the previous code I had wouldn't save anything because it'd replace the saved values with `_` and in order to fix this,

```
for (let i = 0; i < underlineArr.length; i++) {
    if (content !== word.toLowerCase()[i]) continue;
    underlineArr[i] = word.toLowerCase()[i];
}
```